# Give particular privileges for a table to existing role

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.4

My database have some tables such as:

Table A
Table B
Table C

I'm using user `monitoring` with read-only permission.

```
SELECT grantee, privilege_type 
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE table_name= 'Table A'
```

[image]

I want to set `monitoring` user with `insert`, `update`, `delete`, `truncate`, `alter table`, `trigger` permission for only table `Table A`. The another table don't affect. How to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GRANT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html).

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, TRIGGER ON table A TO monitoring;
```

The role needs privileges for the DB and the schema, too, but since it already has the `SELECT` privilege, that should be the case. And if you want to keep `SELECT` and `REFERENCES` in the mix, you can just:

```
GRANT ALL ON table A TO monitoring;
```

But only superuser or the owner of a table can [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html). The manual:

> You must own the table to use `ALTER TABLE`.

You would have to make the role `monitoring` the owner. (Do you really want that??)

```
ALTER TABLE A OWNER TO monitoring;
```

Related:

- [How to manage DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for USERs on a DATABASE vs SCHEMA?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117109/how-to-manage-default-privileges-for-users-on-a-database-vs-schema/117661#117661)