# How to change owner of a table within a PostgreSQL Database on Azure?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, azure

I attempting to restore a database into a PostgreSQL instance on Azure.

I am issuing these statements as postgres and attempting to change owner to another role that ***was*** a superuser.

My restore errors on this line (actual names changed to protect the innocent):

`ALTER TABLE schema_m.table_a OWNER TO role_a;`

**SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: must be member of role "role_a"**
I've tried:  `GRANT postgres TO role_a GRANTED BY postgres;`

I believe the issue is related to the postgres user not being a superuser on Azure PostgreSQL, but maybe I'm wrong.

I've also tried granted all privs to both:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA  schema_m TO role_a;
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA  schema_m  TO postgres;
```

But I still receive the error. Am I missing something obvious?

```
PostgreSQL 9.5.14, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit
```

Comment: You forgot two essential bits of information: your version of Postgres (always) and the current role of the session where you issue those statements. (Is it `postgres`?)

Comment: Added. That's the problem--role_a can't be a superuser in the Azure env. like it was in my source database.

Comment: `postgres` and `role_a` are definitely not superuser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46674322/386619

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't seem to be specific to Azure. It's a general rule in Postgres: Only the owner or a superuser can use `ALTER TABLE`.

To verify your role is a superuser (or not), run in the current session:

```
SELECT rolsuper FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = current_user;
```

Related:

- [Give particular privileges for a table to existing role](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205644/give-particular-privileges-for-a-table-to-existing-role/205647#205647)

Comment: There is also the option to have user "user_a" and "user_b" be members of the role "role_a" and alter ownerhsip of the table to role "role_a" which then allows "user_a" and "user_b" to alter the table.