# Permissions for runtime user on all objects in schema (including future objects)

Tags: postgresql, permissions, schema, postgresql-10

In PostgreSQL 10 - when using an "owner user" (login role owning a schema and all tables, not used by the application at runtime) and a "runtime" user I can `GRANT` Select/Update/Delete permissions on all *existing* tables in the schema to the runtime user:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA owner TO runtime;
```

But this only applies to existing objects and not new tables which might get created later on.

Is there a way to avoid granting on all new objects by way of inheriting roles or schema permissions or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The key word is [`DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html#SQL-ALTERDEFAULTPRIVILEGES-NOTES).

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE owner_user IN SCHEMA owner 
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO runtime;
```

Grants the specifies privileges for all specified objects created **in the future**, by the specified role to the other specified role.

I specified the *target_role* (`owner_user`) explicitly to avoid ambiguity. Else, [quoting the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html#SQL-ALTERDEFAULTPRIVILEGES-NOTES):

> If `FOR ROLE` is omitted, the current role is assumed.

Related:

- [Grant all on a specific schema in the db to a group role in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352695/grant-all-on-a-specific-schema-in-the-db-to-a-group-role-in-postgresql/10353730#10353730)
- [How to manage DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for USERs on a DATABASE vs SCHEMA?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117109/how-to-manage-default-privileges-for-users-on-a-database-vs-schema/117661#117661)

And don't forget access to sequences if you have any `serial` columns. The first linked answer has instructions.

Comment: Thanks thats what I was looking for. from the documentaiotn lionk I can see that I could also skip "FOR owner_user" and it would apply to all entries in the schema.

Comment: @eckes: That's a misunderstanding. See clarification above.

Comment: @eckes: BTW, pgAdmin III has a bug, displaying the `FOR target_user` clause incorrectly. Details: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CA%2BOCxow_xcQJiLj0-WVfX-yg-J5FA8wi7Z-LaWjampqpeVVA-Q%40mail.gmail.com#64cc3c9a1d2816db7b0fc7dc2223bd93 You are not the first to be confused by this. :)