# why do I need \connect hostdb

Tags: postgresql

In the answer to [How to manage DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for USERs on a DATABASE vs SCHEMA?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117109/how-to-manage-default-privileges-for-users-on-a-database-vs-schema?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I see the line `\connect hostdb` why and when do I need this line?

I'm executing role creations SQL line from a .sql file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's needed because the target database for the rest of that script is created just in the line above that statement. However creating a new database doesn't automatically switch to that database. In order for all following statements to be executed against that new database, the connection needs to be switched to that database.